# mysql_query issues with inserting information

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I have a problem with one of my queries - it seems not to be inserting any of the values into my database. Below is the code I am using for a form submitting.

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $assignment_data = array(
        'title'         => $_POST['title'],
        'number'        => $_POST['number'],
        'weighting'     => $_POST['weight'],
        'handout'       => $_POST['handout'],
        'handin'        => $_POST['handin'],
        'feedback'      => $_POST['feedback'],
        'wordcount'     => $_POST['wordcount'],
        'brief'         => $_POST['brief'],
        'sub_details'   => $_POST['details'],
        'add_note'  => $_POST['notes']
    );

    create_assignment($assignment_data);
    //header('Location: modules.php');
    //exit();
}
function create_assignment($assignment_data) {
    array_walk($assignment_data, 'array_sanitize');

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($assignment_data)) . '`';
    $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $assignment_data) . '\'';

    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `assignments` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
    echo $fields;
    echo $data;
    $test = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());;

    print $test;
}

?>
```

I am getting this as the result from entering information into the form and submitting it:

```
`title`, `number`, `weighting`, `handout`, `handin`, `feedback`, `wordcount`, `brief`,
`sub_details`, `add_note`

'Dream Design', '2', '20', '07/01/2014', '08/01/2014', '08/01/2014', '2', 'asd',
'asdasd', 'asdasdasd'

Query was empty.
```

The information is being placed in the $fields and $data variables but seems to be not running the query... Nothing is being inserted into my database.

Any help or assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your query look like after the variables are interpolated?

Comment: what is your `mysql_error()` ??

Comment: $query = ("INSERT INTO `assignments` ($fields) VALUES ($data)"); - you are using mysql_query twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `assignments` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
```

and then

```
$test = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());;
                    ^^^^^^--- result of previous query
```

You can't use a query handle to "re-run" a query. You need to save your query into a variable, and re-use that. e.g.

```
$sql = "INSERT ...";

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$test = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Your first query is probably failing, returning a boolean FALSE. That false, when passed in to another query call, will be type-cast to an empty string, hence your "empty query" error message. Adding the `or die(...)` business will tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks for the great explanation. I found out the problem from using the error message as well. I forgot to set a default value for a field in the table - silly me!

Answer (score 0):

You've run mysql_connect, right?

Try mysql_stat() to make sure.

You can also try to get some error output right in the first query:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `assignments` ($fields) VALUES ($data)") or die(mysql_error());
```

And please please please consider using PDO, a framework, or at least mysqli_

Comment: I know I should be using PDO/mysqli, I've only recently picked up learning PHP and this is what the tutorial I used taught me sadly - I will be redoing all the queries for PDO once I have a better grasp and understanding though! :)